# What's the best way to iterate through a pair and update the first element with the second one in Rust?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to do something like this:

```rust
let (a, b) in ass.as_mut_iter().zip(&bs) {
  *a = b;
}
```

Comment: What are `as` (invalid identifier btw) and `bs`?

Comment: `as` -> `ass`. And does it matter what they are?

Answer (score 0):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut ass = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let bs = vec![4, 5, 6];
    for (a, b) in ass.iter_mut().zip(&bs) {
      *a = *b;
    }
    
    dbg!(ass);

}
```

seems to work https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=edad99b5cafa850203e93742057c2ac2

Comment: Is that the solution you where looking for or are you looking for something else?

Comment: no that's the solution! For some reason I thought I couldn't have an iterator that could track both mutable and immutable content

Comment: As long as `ass` and `bs` are of same type and same size you don't need to iterate: `mem::replace(&mut ass, bs);`…